# UNITY2D: Trouble running a CoRoutine from another script

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have written a function on a script that activates when the player loses all his lives. That calls a CoRoutine in a script attached to my main character that makes a simple death animation and then moves to the game over screen. Debug.Log shows that the function calls, and when I use non-CoRoutine functions attached to the main character, those functions call to. However, the CoRoutine itself never calls, not even showing the log of it ever activating? Does anyone know what is up?

Code included below:

```
if (GameObject.Find("Heart 1") == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Naw");
            player.DeathAnimation(20);
            Debug.Log("still not working");
        }


public IEnumerator DeathAnimation(int i)
    {
        int k = i;
        Debug.Log("Numerator works");
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 9);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.08f);
        k--;
        Debug.Log(k);
        if (k <= 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Game Over");
            yield break;
        }
        StartCoroutine(DeathAnimation(k));
    }
```

Comment: The operations related to animation are all in the library. Through the using reference, only two functions are used here, one is LoadScene - loading the scene, and the other is GetActiveScene - the name of the current scene, but generally it is not immediately restarted after death. , if you want to delay a few seconds before calling a function, you can use Invoke("Restart",1f);//The first parameter is the name of the function to call, and the second parameter is the delay time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn’t seem to be a reason to make this a recursive coroutine. I’d suggest removing the recursion which might also solve the issue you’re having or at least make it simpler to identify.

```
    if (GameObject.Find("Heart 1") == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hmm");
        StartCoroutine( player.DeathAnimation(20) );
        Debug.Log("maybe working");
    }
```

…

```
public IEnumerator DeathAnimation(int i)
{
    Debug.Log("Numerator works");
    for( ; i>0; i-- ) {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 9);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.08f);
        Debug.Log(i);
    }
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Game Over");
}
```